# Connecting to an ipv6 ssl server using pyopenssl

Tags: python-2.7, ssl, pyopenssl

I need to connect to ipv6 server using pyopenssl .Is that even possible?For ipv4 i don't have any problem.This is what i'v tried for ipv6:

```
ctx = SSL.Context(SSL.SSLv23_METHOD)
ctx.set_verify(SSL.VERIFY_NONE, verify_cb)
ctx.use_privatekey_file (os.path.join(dir, 'client.pkey'))
ctx.use_certificate_file(os.path.join(dir, 'client.cert'))
ctx.load_verify_locations(os.path.join(dir, 'CA.cert'))
#Set up client
sock = SSL.Connection(ctx, socket.socket(socket.AF_INET6, socket.SOCK_STREAM))
sock.connect(('fe80::3a63:bbff:fe31:3013%ens32',443,0,0))
```

But i'm getting the following error:

```
sock.connect(('fe80::3a63:bbff:fe31:3013%ens32',443,0,0))
  File "/root/Desktop/PY/ilodos2/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 1455, in connect
    return self._socket.connect(addr)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/socket.py", line 228, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
error: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

The documentation of pyopenssl does not talk about ipv6 at all. If pyopenssl cant be used for ipv6, are there any other modules using which i can do ssl renegotiation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem itself isn't really related to PyOpenSSL, when you're using scoped (link local) ipv6 addresses you neeed to pass the correct `scopeid` [as the fourth item of the `address` tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket-families):

> ...
>   For AF_INET6 address family, a four-tuple (host, port, flowinfo, scopeid) is used, where flowinfo and scopeid represent the sin6_flowinfo and sin6_scope_id members in struct sockaddr_in6 in C. For socket module methods, flowinfo and scopeid can be omitted just for backward compatibility. **Note, however, omission of scopeid can cause problems in manipulating scoped IPv6 addresses.**

Consult `ip addr` to show the correct numerical scope id, e.g. with scopeid 2 for ens32 the following should work:

```
sock.connect(('fe80::3a63:bbff:fe31:3013%ens32', 443, 0, 2))
```

Or use `getaddrinfo()` to get the correct address:

```
ainfo = socket.getaddrinfo('fe80::3a63:bbff:fe31:3013%ens32', 443, socket.AF_INET6, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
address = ainfo[0][4]
```